# Does solidity support operator overloading?

Tags: solidity

Wondering if solidity supports operator overloading like python does?

Something like:

---WARNING PSEUDOCODE---

```
overload __+__ {
    if (type(arg1) == string && type(arg2) == string){
        return arg1.append(arg2);
    }
}
```

I would use this to rewrite the SafeMath library, as SafeMath adding/multiplying/etc. in a long string becomes very unreadable...

Cheers!

Comment: Solidity doesn't support operator overloading.

Comment: @Ismael thank you! I do remember reading something about this in a Vitalik blog post, but I don't recall the specifics. Perhaps in the future...

Answer (score 3):

The official solidity [documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html?highlight=overload#function-overloading) only mentions function overloading.

There is **no** operator overloading in Solidity.

Answer (score 2):

As of 0.8.19, you can now define custom operators for types https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.19/contracts.html#using-for

https://github.com/PaulRBerg/prb-math/blob/main/src/ud60x18/ValueType.sol#L82

Is a good example where it states:

```
using {
    Helpers.add as +,
    Helpers.and2 as &,
    Math.div as /,
    Helpers.eq as ==,
    Helpers.gt as >,
    Helpers.gte as >=,
    Helpers.lt as <,
    Helpers.lte as <=,
    Helpers.or as |,
    Helpers.mod as %,
    Math.mul as *,
    Helpers.neq as !=,
    Helpers.not as ~,
    Helpers.sub as -,
    Helpers.xor as ^
} for UD60x18 global;
```

to override the basic operations for a custom integer type.

Answer (score 1):

No, Solidity doesn't support operator overloading as of Jan 2018.